# IOS: Retrieve sms history

Tags: cocoa, list, ios, sms, history

Is it possible to access the sms history with cocoa touch?
Which class and methods do i need to lookup?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you can't access a user's SMS records from within your applications. Anything along the lines of getting a user's telephony history is strictly out of bounds for apps.